# How does mod_wsgi know and execute the application?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm tying to setup Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3

I manage to get the WSGIScriptAlias executed, but only the top level module code, not the `application` defined therein.

Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias  /testurl /home/django/test/test/wsgi_test.py

<Directory /home/django/test/test>
<Files wsgi_test.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

wsgi_test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print >> sys.stderr, "I'm wsgi_test"

def application(environ, start_response):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'in application'
        status = '200 OK'
        output = 'hello World'
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output]
```

When requesting the url using a browser the `wsgi_test.py` script gets executed ("I'm wsgi_test" appearing in the apache error log). However, no page is served (500 internal server error) and there is an additional error log entry *Premature end of script headers: wsgi_test.py*.

As a second test, I used a simple script, which correctly serves 'Hello World':

wsgi_test2.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print 'Content-type: text/plain\n\n'
print 'Hello World'
```

My question:
**How does mod_wsgi know and execute the application?**

From the above tests, I conclude that `wsgi_test.py` is immediately executed. Since there is no executable code but only a definition of `application`, the script does not output anything and thus the server complains about the missing html headers. How do I tell the system to run the `application`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod_wsgi module does not execute the script in the way that you are likely thinking. That is, it doesn't run them as a program.

Your Apache configuration is likely setup so that files with `.py` extension are being executed as a CGI script and so this is not actually being handled by mod_wsgi. This would explain the behaviour you are seeing.

Either disable `AddHandler` directive which makes `.py` files CGI scripts, or rename your WSGI scripts to have a `.wsgi` extension and change the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive to match.

When this is done, then mod_wsgi will load the WSGI script into memory and then run the Python code in the memory of the server processes. So not as a separate program execution.

If you ensure that the `LogLevel` directive in Apache is set to `info` if currently set to `warn`, then you should see a lot more messages logged by mod_wsgi about when it is loading the WSGI script to run it the first time. This will confirm that mod_wsgi is handling them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really a nasty pitfall, especially since the default django wsgi file is named `wsgi.py` (from which I was starting my tests). Shouldn't it better be `project.wsgi` or similar?

Comment: The mod_wsgi documentation has always generally recommended a ``.wsgi`` extension and for more reasons than just this. It was suggested that Django should also generate a ``.wsgi`` file, which then imported the ``wsgi.py``, but suggestion was ignored. Ultimately though the fault here lies with the Linux distribution for adding a default in the Apache configuration that forces ``.py`` to CGI for all directories and not just the ``cgi-bin`` directory. This problem doesn't affect everyone though. So are you sure you did uncomment something in the default Apache configuration to enable it.

Comment: The problem occured with a preconfigured apache on a webhosting service. I did not change the default configuration. However, it may well be that the webhoster did so.

Comment: Yep, would have been the web hosting service then. They generally don't have any idea of what is the appropriate thing to do for Python.